# Require image with space in image name throws error

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently working on a soundboard app, and I'm using ListItem for creating buttons. It allows me to create buttons with little avatars. I'm keeping monster data in an array.

I've already tried to replace('%20', '') method after the path to image but it didn't work for me.

Here is some code:

```
{
  "name": "Smoczy zębacz", 

  "image": {source: require('./assets/img/Smoczy zębacz.jpg')},  

  "sound": require('./assets/sounds/Smoczy zębacz.mp3')
}
```

It works well when image and sound name don't contain space.

I want this code to find image with space in it's name but I'am getting this error:

```
Error: Asset not found: C:\Users\user\Soundboard\assets\img\Smoczy%20zębacz.jpg for platform: android
at C:\Users\user\Soundboard\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js:147:13
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (C:\Users\user\Soundboard\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js:326:347)
at C:\Users\user\Soundboard\node_modules\metro\src\Assets.js:326:507
```

When I click on it I also get the same error with mp3 file.

Comment: This was resolved as a facebook issue on **Oct, 2016**. Follow [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/10365) link.

Comment: Have you tried it with non space filename?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly when filename doesn't contain space.

Answer (score 0):

I think your wrongly use the url

your are using image url

C:\Users\user\Soundboard\assets\sounds\Smoczy%20zębacz.jpg

instead of mp3 url

C:\Users\user\Soundboard\assets\sounds\Smoczy%20zębacz.mp3

Comment: Sorry I copied error wrong in my question, I've alredy edited it and now it shows it as it should.